# Castle Windsor - How to resolve interfaces created using abstract factory pattern

Tags: vb.net, castle-windsor

I am using abstract factory pattern to instantiate objects. And I have allocated only one class (public class) to the clients to instantiate 
an object and that object have methods  to instantiate other objects(Friend classes only to that assembly).

Now I want to implement the Castle-Windsor to resolve my interfaces. All my objects creation logic to an interface  is sitting in my Public class.

How can I resolve my interface using the object that has  methods of the same return type of interface.

BE Interface ->

```
Public Interface IDependency1
    Property DoSomething As String
End Interface
Public Interface IDependency2
    Property DoSomething2 As String
End Interface
Public Interface IDependencyAll
   Readonly Property Dependency1() As IDependency1
    Function Dependency2() As IDependency2
End Interface
```

BL Implementaions ->

```
Friend Class Dependency1
    Implements IDependency1

    Private newPropertyValue As String = "Test"
    Public Property DoSomething() As String Implements IDependency1.DoSomething
        Get
            Return newPropertyValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newPropertyValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class



Friend Class Dependency2
    Inherits rbASE
    Implements IDependency2
     Private newPropertyValue As String = "Test"
     Public Property DoSomething2() As String Implements IDependency2.DoSomething2
        Get
            Return newPropertyValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            newPropertyValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class



Public Class Main
    Implements IDependencyAll
    Public Readonly Property Dependency1() As IDependency1 Implements IDependencyAll.Dependency1
        Get
            Return New Dependency1
        End Get
     End Property

    Public Function Dependency2() As IDependency2 Implements IDependencyAll.Dependency2
        Return New Dependency2()
    End Function

End Class
```

Client ->

```
 Dim container = New WindsorContainer()
        'container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(Of BE.Main1)())
        'container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(Of BE.IDependency1)().ImplementedBy(Of BE.Dependency12)())
        'container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(Of BE.IDependency2)().ImplementedBy(Of BE.Dependency22)())
        'Dim mainThing = container.Resolve(Of BE.Main1)()
        'mainThing.DoSomething()
        Dim container1 = New WindsorContainer()
        ' container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BE").Pick.WithService.DefaultInterfaces.LifestyleTransient)
        container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BL").BasedOn(GetType(IDependencyAll)).WithService.Base.LifestyleTransient)
        'container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BL").BasedOn(GetType(IDependency1)).WithService.Base.LifestyleTransient)


        ' container1.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(Of BE.IDependencyAll)().ImplementedBy(Of BL.Main)())
        Dim answer As String = "not resolved properluy"
        Dim IcaseController As IDependencyAll = container1.Resolve(GetType(IDependencyAll))
        Dim p = IcaseController.CreateBI(Of IDependency1)()
        answer = p.DoSomething
        'Dim p = IcaseController.
        Label1.Text = answer
```

It has 2 class library project and 1 UI project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some investigation on this,I figured out that by implementing the XML configuration I can resolve my dependencies.

In this way I can still keep my class as "Internal or Friend " to the class library. I am allowing only the encapsulated class to be visible outside to my client.

With this I don't have to change the access modifier of my classes.I found some other ways also without XML configuration but those changes needs my class modifiers to be changed as "Public".  But i don't want to expose those classes to the client.

BE Code

`Public Interface IDependency1
    Property DoSomething As String
End Interface
Public Interface IDependency2
    Readonly  Property DoSomething2 As String
End Interface`

BL code

```
    Friend Class Dependency1
        Implements IDependency1

        Private newPropertyValue As String = "Test"
        Public Property DoSomething() As String Implements IDependency1.DoSomething
            Get
                Return newPropertyValue
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                newPropertyValue = value
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
     Imports BE

    Friend Class Dependency2
        Implements IDependency2
        Private cc As String
        Public Sub New(cons As String)
            cc = cons
        End Sub
        Public readonly Property DoSomething2 As String Implements IDependency2.DoSomething2
            Get
                Return cc + "test"
            End Get
        End Property

    End Class
    Imports BE
    Imports System.Reflection
    Imports Castle.MicroKernel.Registration
    Imports Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.SpecializedResolvers
    Imports Castle.Windsor
     Public Class MainRepo
        Inherits rbASE
        Implements IDependencyAll
        Function Generate(Of T)(cons As String) As T Implements IDependencyAll.ResolveBL
            Dim container = New WindsorContainer()
            container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(New ArrayResolver(container.Kernel))


    container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig())
        Return container.Resolve(Of T)(New With {.cons = cons})
    End Function 
end class
```

Here is the UI code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    Dim container1 = New WindsorContainer()
    ' container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BE").Pick.WithService.DefaultInterfaces.LifestyleTransient)
    container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BL").BasedOn(GetType(IDependencyAll)).WithService.Base.LifestyleTransient)
    'container1.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("BL").BasedOn(GetType(IDependency1)).WithService.Base.LifestyleTransient)

    ' container1.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(New CustomArrayResolver(container1.Kernel, GetType(IDependencyAll())))

    ' container1.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For(Of BE.IDependencyAll)().ImplementedBy(Of BL.Main)())

    Dim answer As String = "not resolved properluy"
    Dim IcaseController As IDependencyAll = container1.Resolve(Of IDependencyAll)()
    Dim p = IcaseController.ResolveBL(Of IDependency2)("test cons")

    answer = p.DoSomething2
    'Dim p = IcaseController.
    Label1.Text = answer

    ' mainThing1.DoSomething()
End Sub
```

Here is the config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
  </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>


    <castle>
      <components>
        <component id="Dependency1" service="BE.IDependency1, BE" type="BE.IDependency1, BE" />
        <component id="Dependency2" service="BE.IDependency2, BE" type="BL.Dependency2, BL" />
      </components>
    </castle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Me having some problems reading VB code, but if i understand it the right way you mean this

```
public interfaces
IDependency1
IDependency2
IDependencyAll (provides access to IDependency1 and IDependency2)


internal componenets
Dependency1 implementing IDependency1
Dependency2 implementing IDependency2

public components
Main implementing IDependencyAll
```

So you will have two options

1. Allow property injection. Windsor then injects dependencies during resolving of Main. (requires public setter on property)
2. Create a constructor for Main having your IDependency1 and IDependency2 as parameters. Windsor then passes dependencies during instance creation of Main (you have to assign your properties from within your constructor)

If it helps i can provide you C# code of what i mean.

Comment: I will try with Property Injection with Castle Windsor.